# Are any Narrations of the Sahabah responding to Requests of Du'a by Saying they're not a Prophet?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, prophet-muhammad, sunnah, prophets

Obviously Asking People to make Du'a is permissible but I was reading  ash-Shaatibi's  book Al-I’tisaam where he ( Seemingly) Quotes Tabari Sa’d Ibn Abi Waqqaas refusing to make Du'a when a crowd gathered and asked if he was a prophet.

وأخرج ابن جرير عن سعد بن أبي وقاص أنه لما قدم الشام أتاه رجل فقال له: "استغفر لي"، وكان سعد مجاب الدعوة، فقال له سعد: "غفر الله لك"، ثم أتاه آخر، فقال: "استغفر لي"، فقال له: "لا غفر الله لك، ولا غفر الله لذاك، أنبي أنا؟"، فلما خرجت فلتة من ذاك الرجل قال: "غفر الله لك"، ولما تزاحم عليه الناس قال: "لا غفر لله لك ولا غفر الله لذاك، أنبي أنا؟"

There's also a similar Narration from Umar where he responds similarly ( Also Quoted from Ibn Jarir) However I looked Online for the orginal source to look at the Isnad but i could not find it so i have come to the conclusion perhaps its from book lost to us, Although i could be wrong.

I have read ash-Shaatibi's explanation where he said they don't someone to think it's a sunnah which makes sense but i am wondering if there is any narrations (With a Isnad) which indicated that asking du'a is best to asked from a prophet as part of their special Status of a Prophet?

Comment: Are you looking for the given quote, for others from a-Shatibi's book or any such quotes? As for the quotes of ibn Jarir at-Tabari it is most likely that they come from his book "تهذيب الآثار" as a-Shatibi himself said after quoting them (see for example [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32120/813#p1) and [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31718/482#p1)). A huge part of it is lost and at-Tabari died before completing the book only the Musnad's of 'Umar, 'Ali and ibn 'Abbas reached us further reached us the Musnads of 'Abdurrahman ibn 'Awf and Talha which are referred to as the missing part.

Comment: Medi1Saif I was looking for other Similar quotes not necessarily from the same book  by Companions why place emphasis on prophets are one to ask du'as from. But thank you for telling me about the book being Tahdhib al-Athar, i wasn't sure if it was from it or not?